# How to make this search faster in fgrep/Ag?

Tags: grep, time, parallelism, ag

I am thinking methods to make the search faster and/or better which principally uses `fgrep` or `ag`. 
Code which searches the word `and` case-insensitively at `$HOME`, and redirects a list of matches to `vim`

```
find -L $HOME -xtype f -name "*.tex" \
   -exec fgrep -l -i "and" {} + 2>/dev/null | vim -R -
```

It is faster with `ag` because of parallelism and `ack`

```
find -L $HOME -xtype f -name "*.tex" \
   -exec ag -l -i "and" {} + 2>/dev/null | vim -R -
```

### Statistics

Small group average statistics with `fgrep` and `ag` by `time`

```
        fgrep   ag     terdon1  terdon2  terdon3  muru 
user    0.41s   0.32s  0.14s    0.22s    0.18s    0.12s
sys     0.46s   0.44s  0.26s    0.28s    0.30s    0.32s
```

Cases `terdon1` and `terdon3` can be equal fast. 
I get great fluctuations with those two. 
Some Ranking by `sys` time (not best criteria!)

1. terdon1
2. terdon2
3. terdon3
4. muru
5. ag
6. fgrep

### Abbreviations

- terdon1 = terdon-many-find-grep
- terdon2 = terdon-many-find-fgrep
- terdon3 = terdon-many-find-ag (without F because not exists in `ag`)

### Other codes

muru's proposal in comments

```
grep -RFli "and" "$HOME" --include="*.tex" | vim -R -
```

OS: Debian 8.5
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What about just grep? `grep -Rfli and "$HOME" --include-files="*.tex"`?

Comment: You might find "ripgrep" interesting. It's the a newer (and usually faster) tool in the vein of ack/ag/pt.

Comment: @Masi oh, sorry, that should be `-RFli`, F, not f

Comment: Sigh, another mistake. It should be just `--include`, not `--include-files`. Corrected: `grep -RFli and "$HOME" --include="*.tex"`

Comment: perhaps use locate instead of find - if you can accept out-of-date find results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably make it a little bit faster by running multiple `find` calls in parallel. For example, first get all toplevel directories and run N find calls, one for each dir. If you run the in a subshell, you can collect the output and pass it to vim or anything else:

```
shopt -s dotglob ## So the glob also finds hidden dirs
( for dir in $HOME/*/; do 
    find -L "$dir" -xtype f -name "*.tex" -exec grep -Fli and {} + & 
  done
) | vim -R -
```

Or, to be sure you only start getting output once all the finds have finished:

```
( for dir in $HOME/*/; do 
    find -L "$dir" -xtype f -name "*.tex" -exec grep -Fli and {} + & 
  done; wait
) | vim -R -
```

I ran a few tests and the speed for the above was indeed slightly faster than the single `find`. On average, over 10 runs, the single `find` call tool 0.898 seconds and the subshell above running one find per dir took 0.628 seconds.

I assume the details will always depend on how many directories you have in `$HOME`, how many of them could contain `.tex` files and how many might match, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I think `-l` implies `-m1`.

Comment: @muru ah, yes it does. Which explains why I saw no difference when I added it :) Thanks.

Comment: @masi none, as far as I know. It's just that there will be a trade-off between running multiple finds and having the disk seek multiple locations. This sort of thing will always depend on the specific setup you have.

Comment: I tested some different algorithms in your proposal with `fgrep` and `ag`. Which of those approaches should be fastest in theory? - - There are some great fluctuations with your approach and your approach with `ag`. - - I think your approach may be the fastest but your appoach with `ag` is almost as fast but cannot confirm the result yet.

Comment: Note that ripgrep will automatically parallelize directory traversal for you.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're using `ack` and The Silver Searcher (`ag`), it seems that you are OK with using additional tools.

A new tool in this space is ripgrep (`rg`). It is designed to be fast in both *finding* files to search (like `ag`) and also fast in *searching* files themselves (like plain old GNU `grep`).

For the example in your question, you might use it something like this:

```
rg --files-with-matches --glob "*.tex" "and" "$HOME"
```

The author of ripgrep [posted a detailed analysis](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/) of how the different searching tools work, along with benchmark comparisons.

One of the benchmarks, [`linux-literal-casei`](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/#linux-literal), is somewhat similar to the task you describe. It searches over a large number of files in a lot of nested directories (the Linux codebase), searching for a case-insensitive string literal.

In that benchmark, `rg` was fastest when using a whitelist (like your "*.tex" example). The `ucg` tool also did well on this benchmark.

> ```
> rg (ignore)         0.345 +/- 0.073 (lines: 370)
> rg (ignore) (mmap)  1.612 +/- 0.011 (lines: 370)
> ag (ignore) (mmap)  1.609 +/- 0.015 (lines: 370)
> pt (ignore)        17.204 +/- 0.126 (lines: 370)
> sift (ignore)       0.805 +/- 0.005 (lines: 370)
> git grep (ignore)   0.343 +/- 0.007 (lines: 370)
> rg (whitelist)      0.222 +/- 0.021 (lines: 370)+
> ucg (whitelist)     0.217 +/- 0.006 (lines: 370)*
> ```
>
> * - Best mean time.
>   + - Best sample time.

The author excluded `ack` from the benchmarks because it was much slower than the others.

Comment: I opened a ticket about Debian installation option of `rg` here https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/291 Let's hope there will be something soon.

Comment: You can download self contained binaries here: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/releases --- Debian packages are being worked on. Ripgrep should be one of the first Rust programs packaged!

Comment: @BurntSushi5 Please, let us know when the apt-get built of `rg` is ready. I want to try it as soon as possible.

Comment: You can try it now by just downloading the binary on github. Just drop it into your $HOME/bin and you're good to go! (But sure,  I'll try to remember to leave a comment here when it is actually packaged.)